# libQtDeclarative.so not found

Tags: android, qt, qtdeclarative

I'm new to QT Programming

Here's what I did,
I export photo from photoshop to QT
after that I create new QT QUICK PROJECT ( ANDROID )
and open QT DESIGNER FILE which I exported earlier from photoshop

run through ministro,
but my this error occurred

```
> 
Starting remote process ...
D/dalvikvm( 2148): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm( 2148): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 3% free 9074K/9347K, paused 133ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 2148): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.393MB for 1536016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
D/dalvikvm( 2148): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 10573K/10887K, paused 6ms+134ms
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm( 2148): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 10573K/10887K, paused 49ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 2148): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.688MB for 3456016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
D/dalvikvm( 2148): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 13948K/14279K, paused 8ms+7ms
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/gralloc_goldfish( 2148): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
I/dalvikvm( 2148): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 2148): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm( 2148): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'QtIndustrius-14.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
D/dalvikvm( 2148): DexOpt: --- END 'QtIndustrius-14.jar' (success) ---
D/dalvikvm( 2148): DEX prep '/data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/jar/QtIndustrius-14.jar': unzip in 159ms, rewrite 749ms
D/dalvikvm( 2148): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtCore.so 0x412a98f0
D/dalvikvm( 2148): Added shared lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtCore.so 0x412a98f0
D/dalvikvm( 2148): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtCore.so 0x412a98f0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 2148): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtGui.so 0x412a98f0
D/dalvikvm( 2148): Added shared lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtGui.so 0x412a98f0
D/dalvikvm( 2148): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtGui.so 0x412a98f0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 2148): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/plugins/platforms/android/libandroid-9.so 0x412a98f0
D/dalvikvm( 2148): Added shared lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/plugins/platforms/android/libandroid-9.so 0x412a98f0
I/Qt ( 2148): qt start
D/dalvikvm( 2148): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.kde.necessitas.example.HOME/lib/libHOME.so 0x412a98f0
W/System.err( 2148): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
W/System.err( 2148): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2148): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 2148): at org.kde.necessitas.origo.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:144)
W/System.err( 2148): at org.kde.necessitas.origo.QtActivity.access$200(QtActivity.java:77)
W/System.err( 2148): at org.kde.necessitas.origo.QtActivity$3$1$1.run(QtActivity.java:201)
W/System.err( 2148): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
W/System.err( 2148): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err( 2148): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 2148): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
W/System.err( 2148): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2148): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 2148): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
W/System.err( 2148): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
W/System.err( 2148): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2148): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]: 36 could not load needed library 'libQtDeclarative.so' for 'libHOME.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libQtDeclarative.so' not found)
W/System.err( 2148): at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:340)
W/System.err( 2148): at java.lang.System.load(System.java:521)
W/System.err( 2148): at org.kde.necessitas.industrius.QtNative.loadBundledLibraries(QtNative.java:125)
W/System.err( 2148): at org.kde.necessitas.industrius.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:245)
W/System.err( 2148): ... 14 more
> Blockquote
```

and I think It is because of this

36 could not load needed library 'libQtDeclarative.so' for 'libHOME.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libQtDeclarative.so' not found)

I Use
ARMV5
Android Emulator

Someone help me please.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple questions:
Did you select Qt Quick Application in Necessitas? Looking at the output it seems as if its not packaging the Declarative module with the application.

What you can try is going into the run settings tab, extending the dropdowns and navigating to the package area. make sure QDeclarative is included. it should do this by default, but without knowing exactly how it was setup, its hard to guess why it did.

Key point, in the 'Package Configuration' area of the run settings, you will see a tab called libraries. Make sure QDeclarative is included.

Also, make sure the declarative module is declared in the .pro file

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello it works but how can I declare declrative module in the .pro file? Thank you